# WebStorm @angular/material data table template errors

Tags: angular-material, webstorm

I have an issue using the WebStorm JetBrains IDE and the **@angular/material** v5.0.0 library. When trying to use the mat-table component I have template errors: [image: Template errors screenshot]

I have tried disabling the Angular language service, but this does not make any sense. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

there are 2 issues here:

- material table structural directives are reported as unknown when using asterisk notation (like `*matRowDef`): [WEB-29827](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29827)
- passing implicit context to template input variable causes syntax errors: [WEB-26939](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26939)

Comment: So I should wait until JetBrains fix this issue? Maybe somehow I can turn off these errors?

Comment: you can get rid of the first one by adding `*matRowDef`, etc. to custom HTML attributes: hit `Alt+Enter` on the highlighted directive, choose **Add *matRowDef to custom HTML attributes**. the second one comes fro lexer and can't be disabled